# JavaScript file is shown on Japanese(or other Asian language)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-10

I have an ASP.NET MVC installed on a server and when I go to the page from a virtual machine using IE10 a javascript error is shown, when I look in the IE Developers tools the error is SCRIPT1014: Invalid character. I try to debug the jscript but the code looks like Japanese kanjis(??) This **only** happens from this machine and only on IE10. Anyone know if I can resolve this problem?(I cant change the windows language, the machine is from a customer and I dont have admin rights).

Comment: is the file using utf8 file encoding? if not try to save the file so it uses utf8 (this is usually a setting in the save dialog box)

Comment: Definitely an encoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was enconding, I changed the encoding and worked. I opened the .js file on Notepad++ and select encoding and changed from UCS2 little endian to UTF-8

Comment: Please add a full explanation, it may help other people with the same question. What was the old encoding? How did you changed it?